# Android: ArrayList from Message

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist, type-conversion

My problem is convert a Message type in a ArrayList type.
The code that i use is:

```
private final ResponseHandler<String> myResponseHandlerTopTen = new ResponseHandler<String>()
    {
    @Override
    public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
        {
        ...
        ArrayList arrayRow = new ArrayList();
        ...
        toMainThread(arrayRow);
        ...
        }
    }


private void toMainThread(ArrayList message)
    {
    Message messageToSend = myHandlerTopTen.obtainMessage();
    messageToSend.obj = message;
    myHandlerCode.sendMessage(messageToSend);
    }

myHandlerCode = new Handler()
    {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        /* ## if msg is string: ##
        String ExtractData=msg.obj.toString();
        */
        /* msg is an ArrayList */
        ArrayList ExtractData=msg.obj. ?????
        }
    };
```

Using:

```
private void toMainThread(String message)
```

I can use

```
String ExtractData=msg.obj.toString();
```

but using:

```
private void toMainThread(ArrayList message)
```

I must use ??

Thank's, very very thank's for answer ;-)
Daniele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to be able to just cast to ArrayList:

```
ArrayList extractData = (ArrayList) msg.obj;
```

Comment: It was so easy that it was difficult for me
`THANKS`